# $f_{\mu}$ is a monotonic non-decreasing function

Tags: measure-theory, monotone-functions

I don't know to solve this exercise:

> Let $\mathcal{B}_\mathbb{R}$ the $\sigma$-algebra of Borel subsets in $\mathbb{R}$ and let $\mu :  \mathcal{B}_\mathbb{R} \rightarrow{} \mathbb{R}_{+}$  a finite measure. For each $x \in \mathbb{R}$ define
> $$f_{\mu} := \mu((- \infty,x]) $$
> Prove that:
> $f_{\mu}$ is a monotonic non-decreasing function

My attempt:

we have to:

If $a<b$

$$f_\mu(b)-f_\mu(a)=\mu((-\infty,b])-\mu(-\infty,a])=\mu((-\infty,a]\cup (a,b])-\mu(-\infty,a]
$$

Comment: Use additivity: $\mu(A\cup B)=\mu(A)+\mu(B)$ if $A,B$ are disjoint Borel sets. Here, $(-\infty,a]$ and $(a,b]$ are disjoint.

Comment: Notice that if $x<y$, then $(-\infty,x]\subset(-\infty,y]$. Since measures are monotone, i.e. $\mu(A)\leq \mu(B)$ whenever $A\subset B$, you obtain that $F_\mu(x)=\mu((-\infty,x])\leq \mu((-\infty,y])=F_\mu(y)$.

Comment: An easy way to conclude that is to note that $(-\infty, a] \subset (-\infty, b]$, so $\mu ((-\infty, a]) \leq \mu((-\infty, b])$. (This is intuitive part). But if you want rigor, should use additivity of measure as said by nejimban.

Comment: So i was late for 30 seconds. )))

Comment: I'm going to use additivity. Thank you